# Combing two dataframes that have matching columns but varying rows for each matching value in the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have two DataFrames that that have matching matching columns but have different associated columns for each of the DFs. I would like to combine the two DFs, not duplicating rows but adding nans where there are no values. From what I have found on SO/internet, anything I have tried has ended with duplicating values.

df1

| coll_id | item_name | item_val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | item_1 | 20 |
| 1 | item_2 | 200 |
| 2 | item_3 | 5 |
| 2 | item_4 | 13 |

df2

| coll_id | stat_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | stat_1 |
| 1 | stat_2 |
| 1 | stat_3 |
| 2 | stat_4 |

```
combined = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'coll_id', how = 'outer')
```

I am getting a result that looks like this

| coll_id | item_name | item_val | stat_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | item_1 | 20 | stat_1 |
| 1 | item_1 | 20 | stat_2 |
| 1 | item_1 | 20 | stat_3 |
| 1 | item_2 | 200 | stat_1 |
| 1 | item_2 | 200 | stat_2 |
| 1 | item_2 | 200 | stat_3 |

I am looking for a result similar to what is seen below, so there are no duplicates in the rows but all the data is accounted for.

| coll_id | item_name | item_val | stat_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | item_1 | 20 | stat_1 |
| 1 | nan | nan | stat_2 |
| 1 | nan | nan | stat_3 |
| 1 | item_2 | 200 | stat_1 |
| 1 | nan | nan | stat_2 |
| 1 | nan | nan | stat_3 |

cheers

Comment: Could you clarify why you want an `NaN` in the second column for row 2? It seems like there is a matching set of rows in the initial two tables ( (1,item_1) and (1,stat_2)), so I'm not clear why that value would be `NaN`. Do you have criteria for when you want a row to display the matching value, and when you want it to be NA?

Comment: @Dacromir The data is column item_name have values associated with each item. Having this duplicated would be duplicating the values. I will update the charts to reflect this detail.